# Wordpress 5.0+ breaks custom field saving

Tags: php, wordpress

Sorry about the code format, CTRL+K is said to move things 4 spaces.  But it doesnt work in Chrome:(

Update:  Amazing, I tried this 4 times.  EAch time it triggered a Chrome Shortcut.  I gave up and submitted this.  It gave an error saying that I had code and did not properly format it.  Then amazingly, Ctrl+K works. Not sure why this is so hard...

ANYWAYS,

I upgraded to WP 5.0 on a customer site and now all of the custom fields do not save....  I was using custom code and now the fields do not show in wordpress.  It seems that everything I try today is not working.  StackOverflow is now the latest to join this...

Id appreciate some help with this if anyone can read the last result.

```
-------------------------
$meta_box = array(
    'id' => 'tunebot-meta-marketing-box',
    'title' => 'Enable Marketing Links?',
    'page' => 'page',
    'context' => 'normal',
    'priority' => 'high',
    'fields' => array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Hide Title?',
            'id' => 'tunebot_hide_titler',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Display Image?',
            'id' => 'tunebot_display_image',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Enable Top Banner?',
            'id' => 'tunebot_banner',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Enable Marketing Links?',
            'id' => 'tunebot_marketing_links',
            'type' => 'checkbox'
        ),

    )
);

add_action('admin_init', 'tunebot_add_box');
// Add meta box
function tunebot_add_box() {
    global $meta_box;
    add_action('post_submitbox_misc_actions', 'tunebot_show_box');
    //add_meta_box($meta_box['id'], $meta_box['title'], 'tunebot_show_box', $meta_box['page'], $meta_box['context'], $meta_box['priority']);
}


/**
 * Shows a box with options bellow it, under the text of the body.
 */
function tunebot_show_box() {
    global $meta_box, $post;

    // Use nonce for verification
    $output = '<input type="hidden" name="tunebot_meta_box_nonce" value="' . wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)) . '"/>';

    foreach($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        // get current post meta data
        $postId = $post->ID;
        $key = 'tb_' . $field['id'];
        $meta = get_post_meta($postId, $field['id'], TRUE);

        $output .= '<div class="misc-pub-section misc-pub-section-last">';

        switch($field['type']) {
            case 'text':
                $output .= '<input type="text" name="' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '"
                               value="' . $meta ? $meta : $field['std'] . '" size="30" style="width:97%"/>' . '<br/>' .
                    $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'textarea':
                $output .= '<textarea name="' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '" cols="60" rows="4"
                                  style="width:97%">' . $meta ? $meta : $field['std'] . '</textarea>' . '<br/>' .
                    $field['desc'];
                break;
            case 'select':
                $output .= '<select name="' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '">';
                foreach($field['options'] as $option) {
                    $output .= '
                <option
                ' . $meta == $option ? ' selected="selected"' : '' . '>' . $option . '</option>';
                }
                $output .= '</select>';
                break;
            case 'radio':
                foreach($field['options'] as $option) {
                    $output .= '<input type="radio" name="' . $key . '" value="' . $option['value'] . '"' . (($meta == $option['value']) ? ' checked="checked"' : '' . ' />' . $option['name']);
                }
                break;
            case 'checkbox':
                $output .= '<input type="checkbox" name="' . $key . '" id="' . $key . '"' . ($meta == "on" ? ' checked="checked"' : '') . ' />';
                break;
        }

        $output .= '<label for="' . $key . '">' . $field['name'] . '</label></div>';
    }

    echo $output;
}

add_action('save_post', 'tunebot_save_data');

function tunebot_save_data($post_id) {
    global $meta_box;

// verify nonce
    if(isset($_POST['tunebot_meta_box_nonce']) && !wp_verify_nonce($_POST['tunebot_meta_box_nonce'], basename(__FILE__))) {
        return $post_id;
    }

// check autosave
    if(defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return $post_id;
    }

// check permissions
    if(isset($_POST['post_type']) && 'page' == $_POST['post_type']) {
        if(!current_user_can('edit_page', $post_id)) {
            return $post_id;
        }
    } elseif(!current_user_can('edit_post', $post_id)) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    foreach($meta_box['fields'] as $field) {
        if(isset($field['id'])) {
            $key = 'tb_' . $field['id'];

            if(isset($_POST[$key])) {
                $new = $_POST[$key];
            } else {
                $new = FALSE;
            }

            $old = get_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], TRUE);

            if($new && $new != $old) {

                update_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $new);
            } elseif('' == $new && $old) {
                delete_post_meta($post_id, $field['id'], $old);
            }

        }
    }
    return $post_id;
}
```

Comment: Disable the Gutenberg plugin to see if that helps

Comment: Actually, the custom field is present but due to change in the visual design of WP Editor you can't add priority value as high because earlier high means it was after title field, now in Gutenberg it disappears as there is no space for field between title and content, So just Change `'priority' => 'high'` to  `'priority' => 'normal',`

Comment: Didn;t fix all the problems.  Not happy about edits.  But I removed the plugin entirely.

Comment: Someone deleted the info on the Stack OVer flow problems. The issues are even worse now.  Entire questions are disappearing now.

Comment: The code you use is very similar to [Meta Box](https://metabox.io) plugin. I'd suggest switching to it, to support Gutenberg.